# Boost variant visitor predefined as global lambda with parameters

Tags: c++, boost, lambda, visitor-pattern

This is follow up on another question that I had a while ago [boost variant simple call to common methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37504740/boost-variant-simple-call-to-common-methods).

Thanks to the suggested idea there I can do

```
boost::apply_visitor([](auto const& obj) { obj.some_operation(); }, variant);
```

I extended the idea and now I have:

```
auto visitor = [](auto const& element) { return element->do_something(); };
```

as a global variable and the visiting it is simply:

```
boost::apply_visitor(visitor, variant);
```

My question is how I can extend this pattern if possible to be able to use it for lambdas that accept additional arguments. Say if I have:

```
auto visitor = [](auto const& element, int a) { return element->do_something(a); };

boost::apply_visitor(<some visitor magic with passing a>, variant);
```

Note that at the time the lambda is defined there is nothing to capture there.

Comment: I don't see the difference between your previous question and this question... The answer is exactly the same. Can you help?

Comment: The first question is how I can apply the same code to all types. This question is about passing arguments.

Comment: Not really. You ask how to pass an extra parameter when using `boost::apply_visitor`, same as here

Comment: oops, sorry, it seems I pasted link to somebodies else question - the question is fixed now

Answer (score 1):

> Note that at the time the lambda is defined there is nothing to capture there.

You may define it later, or define an other one at moment of the call:

```
auto visitor = [](auto const& element, int a) { return element->do_something(a); };

// ... with possible usage of visitor

const int b = ...;
boost::apply_visitor([&](auto const& element) {visitor(element, b);}, variant);
```

Comment: These are good options, but I finished having a full flavoured visitor class that accepts the arguments in the constructor that allows me to do `boost::apply_visitor(visitor(b), variant);`. Note that reusing the implementation is easy to do with a template method. I was just suffering from the 'if all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail' syndrome for a while.